# "None" value for gradient of Tensorflow variables which is used in the network

Tags: tensorflow

I want to develop a custom Seq2Seq in tensorflow and I've created this part of network

```
wflat0 = tf.get_variable("wflat0", shape=(1024, 1024), 
initializer=LinearInitializer)
bflat0 = tf.get_variable("bflat0", shape=1024, initializer=BiasInitializer)

l0flat = selu(tf.matmul(x, wflat0) + bflat0)
x=tf.reshape(l0flat,[shape[0],shape[1],1024])
x = tf.unstack(x, constant.Lstm_cell, 1)
lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LayerNormBasicLSTMCell(LSTMHiddenSize, forget_bias=1.0, dropout_keep_prob=0.9)
outputs, states = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)

decoder = tf.contrib.rnn.LayerNormBasicLSTMCell(LSTMHiddenSize, forget_bias=1.0, dropout_keep_prob=0.9)

y = tf.unstack(tf.reshape(self.y_,[tf.shape(self.y_)[0],tf.shape(self.y_)[1],1]), constant.Lstm_cell, 1)
decoutputs, decstates = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(decoder, y, dtype=tf.float32)

wflat1 = tf.get_variable("wflat1", shape=(LSTMHiddenSize, 128),
                                     initializer=LinearInitializer)
bflat1 = tf.get_variable("bflat1", shape=128, initializer=BiasInitializer)
shapes = tf.shape(decoutputs)
decoutputs=tf.transpose(decoutputs, perm=[1, 0, 2])
decoutputs=tf.reshape(decoutputs,(shapes[0]*shapes[1],shapes[2]))
self.sss=decoutputs
l1flat = selu(tf.matmul(decoutputs, wflat1) + bflat1)
wflat2 = tf.get_variable("wflat2", shape=(128, 1), initializer=LinearInitializer)
bflat2 = tf.get_variable("bflat2", shape=1, initializer=BiasInitializer)
l2flat = tf.matmul(l1flat, wflat2) + bflat2
l2flat = tf.reshape(l2flat,(constant.batchsize , constant.Lstm_cell))
self.sigout=tf.nn.softmax(l2flat)
self.out=l2flat
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=self.out, labels=self.y_))
```

and this network create NAN output after first update iteration for large sequence and it just works for small sequence so I've decided to add gradient clipping and when I was developing that I've found that most of the variables have a none gradient as you can see in this picture
[Image of computed Gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtkY0.png)
how could it possible that some variables which take participate in loss function have a none gradient